# System.Argument Exception When Trying to Render

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to save a snapshot of each slide in the current project as an image file. As part of this, I want to use a `RenderTargetBitmap` to get a `Grid` and its content. Here's the xaml in the `UserControl` that I'm using as a template for each slide:

```
<Grid Background="White" Opacity="0.8" x:Name="ContentGrid">
    <!-- Inking area -->
    <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas"/>
</Grid>
```

And I'm using this to try to get it:

```
RenderTargetBitmap b = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await b.RenderAsync(ContentGrid, 720, 480);
```

I'm then looping through the collection of slides, calling the method on each one.

However, it always throws an error on the `RenderAsync` method. The exception is:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

I've used this method before, and it always worked just fine. The only thing different is that I have an `InkCanvas` in the `Grid`, but I don't see how that would affect anything.

EDIT: Interestingly, even just creating a blank `Grid` with no properties set and trying to render it throws the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I work on the .NET Native runtime and compiler team. I suspect that we've mistakenly stripped off the setter or getter from one of the properties on your UI type. Stopping on all first chance exceptions should show you a stack that has some PropertyInfo/reflection looking goop right before the throw. If so, this can be corrected by adding a few lines to your Default.rd.xml. In particular a few lines like:

```
<Type Name="Full.Namespace.And.Name.Of.UIType" Dynamic="Required All"/>
<Type Name="Full.Namespace.And.Name.Of.OtherUIType" Dynamic="Required All"/>
...
```

If you cannot get it resolved, email us at dotnetnative@microsoft.com and hopfully get you sorted out.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to fix it. I'll send an email to that address.